# Counting the number of strings remaining to be read in standard input using recursion

Tags: java

I want to write a method that has a Scanner parameter associated with a stream of input and counts the number of Strings within the input. However, I have a stack overflow exception. Can you tell me the reason? Thank you a lot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(count(input));
}

public static int count(Scanner input) {

    if (input.hasNextLine())
        return 1 + count(input);
    else
        return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: The `hasNextLine()` call doesn't consume the line, you need to call `nextLine()` in order to move to the next one.

Comment: Counts the number of strings or lines? Do you care about numbers (i.e. `int`, `float`, `long`, ...)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly just strings and I only input strings in my console.

Comment: What delimits or separates the strings (i.e. new lines, spaces, commas, dashes, ...)?

Comment: Why do you think you have to write this using recursion.  That is about the worst possible way to write it as there will always be some number of input lines that will cause a `StackOverflowError` even if you correct the current error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `nextLine()` on `input` in the line `return 1 + count(input)`. You are checking for the next line, but nothing actually consumes it. This means the Scanner never runs out of lines to process.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Could you explain to me what does consumes the line mean or demonstrate me the right code? Java is my first programming language so I have a lot of things to learn.

Comment: @StewieGriffin "Consumes" means that it reads the line from the input.  Say your input has three lines, `A`, `B`, `C`.  Imagine there's a _cursor_ pointing at the beginning of line `A`.  `hasNextLine()` checks to see if there's a line after the cursor, but it doesn't move the cursor.  So every time you call it, the cursor will still be at the beginning of `A`.  Thus you get infinite recursion.  If you call `nextLine()`, it will read the line `A`, and the cursor will now be pointing at `B`.  That's what is meant by "consume".

Comment: What ajb said. You may want to look at the JavaDoc here too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @StewieGriffin Basically scanner.hasNextLine() does not move the cursor and it simply check for the existence of next line. But scanner.nextLine() moves the cursor to the next line.Thats why hasNextLine() just returns a boolean but nextLine returns the actual input string available in next line

Answer (score 1):

Since your question states that you want to count the number of strings in a given input, then the code below will do just that, recursively. The other answer's suggestion counts the number of lines in a given input.

**Note:** `Scanner#next()` uses spaces (`' '`) as the default delimiter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(count(input));
    }

    public static int count(Scanner input) {
        if (input.hasNext()) {
            input.next(); // move Scanner's position to the next string
            return 1 + count(input);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
The dog barks loudly.
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: My IDE reports an error on input on count(input.next()) part

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yep I overlooked that, I updated my answer and corrected it.